# Trouble Executing Tasks in C#

Tags: c#, task

Forgive me if the problem seems obvious. I'm new to programming, started last July. I built a really cool project that prints dozens of Report Types based on a series of Templates. This particular problem happened after I cleaned up some dirty code. I didn't think any changes had been made to these lines.

This line of code worked perfectly before the changes. Now, it seemingly doesn't even open a new process to DoWork().

```
//For Reference: this is in Main()
var PrintingTask = new Task(csvStatements.PrintStatementPDF);
PrinterThreads.Add(PrintingTask);

Parallel.ForEach(PrinterThreads, t =>
{
     t.Start();
});

Task.WaitAll(PrinterThreads.ToArray());
```

I commented that out, and just ran the job as a method call from csvStatements. So I wrote csvStatements.PrintStatementPDF();

In my code, I print statements to a colored template, but I also print them as just text on a white page (so we can use the last of our special papers we used before, which has the template on them).

That task is written like so:

```
//For Reference: this is in my csvStatements object from above.

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvFile))
{
    //2d Array. Left dimension is the page number, Right dimension is the text field number.
    var Fields = new System.Collections.Generic.List<List<string>>();
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        var Field = sr.ReadLine().Split('\t').ToList();
        Fields.Add(Field);
    }

    var BlankVersion = new PrintBlankStatement();
    using (var PrintingTask = new Task(() => BlankVersion.PrintBlankStatementPDF(Fields)))
    {
        PrintingTask.Start();
        //I just added the line below. It wasn't originally there.
        await Task.WhenAll(PrintingTask);

    }
}
```

And, while that tasks runs, the program continues to print the statements to the template. So they should run in parallel. But now, when stepping through the project, the first block of code seemingly executes instantaneously (which is absurd, given the 300 pages of pdfs it needs to do) and doesn't actually produce the pdfs. The second block of code ***somehow*** also exits the program with code 0 (even though that's something done in Main(), which it shouldn't be able to do).

Did I make some change to these tasks that rendered them useless or is it more likely that the error is elsewhere in my project?

Comment: Are you using source code control?

Comment: I'm not really sure what that is, to be honest.

Comment: Then you should drop everything you're doing right now and *learn what it is* and *start using it*. You should not be writing code that is not stored in source code control. I suggest you look into [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git), find some online tutorials, and take the time to bring any source code you have under version control.

Comment: @mason Thanks! Will do. It's just odd because this line of code has been working for months without incident. I just commented it out and ran it without multi-threading and the code works just fine. So it's clearly a problem with my tasks.

Thanks for the link, will read up on it.